# When is the Pokemon from an egg determined?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is the Pokemon that will hatch from an egg determined when the player first obtains the egg from a Pokestop, or when the egg hatches?

It seems like it would make more sense for the Pokemon to be determined as the egg is hatching so this information does not need to be stored, but I have observed that eggs from Pokestops in more populated areas yield better Pokemon than those from Pokestops in smaller towns. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?